# why reverse() function doesn't work properly for StringBuilder?

Tags: java, string

The following code prints true for all the inputs. But when I convert it into String its working properly. whats the reason?

```
StringBuilder s= new StringBuilder();
s.append("abcd");
System.out.println(s.equals(s.reverse()));

output: true

StringBuilder s= new StringBuilder();
s.append("abcd");
System.out.println(s.toString().equals(s.reverse().toString()));
output: false
```

Comment: I suppose it happens because when you call `s.reverse()` you are mutating `s`. So your code is equal to `s.reverse(); s.equals(s);` which is true. On the other hand, Strings are immutable thus when calling `s.toString()` you are actually creating a new object in the heap

Comment: You're comparing the _instance_ of _StringBuilder_, here.  And, not the content; via _toString_.

Comment: Or to put it more  simply, a StringBuilder is not a String, so any expectation that they are interchangeable is misplaced.

Answer (score 4):

The call to `reverse()` does not return a new object. It returns the same `StringBuilder` you called the method on. The following:

```java
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("Foo");
System.out.println(s == s.reverse());
```

Would print `true`. So, doing `s.equals(s.reverse())` is the same as doing `s.equals(s)`<sup>1</sup>, which is going to return true for any valid implementation of `equals`.

That said, your code also assumes `StringBuilder` overrides the `equals` method. It does not.  It inherits the behavior of `Object.equals`, which is the same as `==` (i.e., reference equality). For example, doing:

```java
StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder("Foo");
StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder("Foo");
System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
```

Would print `false` despite the two string builders containing the character sequence `"Foo"`.

So, why does it work when you convert to `String`? Because calling `toString()` creates a new `String` object with the same character sequence as the `StringBuilder` *at the time of the method call*. The returned string is separate from the string builder; any subsequent mutations done to the string builder will not affect the previously returned string.

For example:

```java
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Foo");

String str1 = sb.toString(); // 'str1' contains "Foo"
sb.reverse(); // 'sb' now contains "ooF", but 'str1' still contains "Foo"
String str2 = sb.toString(); // 'str2' contains "ooF"

// Prints false. It is testing if "Foo" is equal to "ooF" (it is not)
System.out.println(str1.equals(str2));
```

Plus, `String` *does* override `equals` so that it compares the characters between the two strings.

---

<sup>1. With regards to the call to `equals`. Doing `s.equals(s.reverse())` will still have the side-effect of reversing the character sequence, whereas `s.equals(s)` obviously will not. The point is that you are testing if an object is equal to itself regardless.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle document says:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse--)
`reverse()` "Causes this character sequence to be **replaced** by the reverse of the sequence". And then it returns the reference to this object `s`.

As soon as you called `s.reverse()`. The actual data; the "abcd" in its location is replaced by the reverse of "abcd". The `StringBuilder` object now contains "dcba".

Now the value of s for s.equals becomes "dcba".

You are basically doing "dcba at location-A".equals("dcba at location-A"), which is true.